# javascript equivalent of jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help what's the javascript equivalent of below jquery line.

```
$("#abc option[value='1']").text();
```

abc is the id of selectbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var options = document.getElementById("abc").options;
for (var i = 0, j = options.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == "1") {
        alert(options[i].text);
    }
}
```

The `value` and `text` attributes are available on the [`HTMLOptionElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257) per DOM Level 2.

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/aQPcm/))

---

**UPDATE**
[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/aQPcm/1/) with combined text, cf. comments:

```
var options = document.getElementById("abc").options,
    text = "";

for (var i = 0, j = options.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == "1") {
        text += options[i].text;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can throw in a `break` statement below the `alert()` in order to stop to loop, cf. @Guffa's answer. But do note @Felix Kling's comment (relevant if there are more than one `option` with `value="1"`.

Comment: Which is not correct (the `break`). Btw. this only works if `#abc` is the select element. I mean, the whole thing works of your assumptions are correct, but it is not 100% equivalent to the selector (but maybe I'm too nitpicky ;))

Comment: @Felix Kling, no I noticed your comment which made me realize the possible mistake. Will update demo.

Answer (score 2):

This would be 100% equivalent to the selector:

```
var options = document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByTagName('option'),
    text = "";

for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    if(option.value === '1') {
        text += option.text;
    }
}
```

Or if `querySelectorAll` is available:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#abc option[value="1"]'),
    text = "";
for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    text += options[i].text;
}
```

That said, you can make improvements depending on the HTML structure (e.g. if `#abc` is the select element etc).

Answer (score 1):

The statement doesn't make sense. It gets the text from an option, and then just throws it away. I assume that you want to do something with the text, like assigning it to a variable.

```
// A variable for the result
var text = null;

// Get the options from the select element
var options = document.getElementById('abc').options;

// Find the option with the value "1"
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].value == '1') {
    // Get the text from the option
    text = options[i].text;
    // Exit from the loop
    break;
  }
}
```

Note: The original code would get the text from all options with the specified value, but this code only gets the text from the first option found. Having more than one option with the same value is pretty useless, so that feature of the original code is most likely unintended.

Comment: The `break` is wrong. `.text()` gets the combined text content of all selected elements.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That depends on whether that is the intention of the original code. Having more than one option with the same value is pretty useless anyway. I'll add a comment so that its clear what the code does.

Comment: Yeah I realized that it depends on what assumptions you make. It is very likely that your code is exactly what the OP intended...

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers it can be:

```
var option = document.querySelector('#abc option[value="1"]').textContent
```

Comment: If you want to be 100% correct, you'd have to use `querySelectorAll`. And `textContent` does not work in IE afaik.

Comment: Old IE have no querySelector and I wrote modern browsers.

Comment: Ah yes, IE9 has `textContent`. Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

This Will Work.

```
document.querySelector(".producer option[value='1']").text;
```